# How would you measure the seebeck coefficient of some material?

Tags: thermoelectricity

Suppose you are given some materials that are viable to be used in a thermocouple. What is a procedure that could be used to measure the Seebeck coefficients of those materials? What apparatus is needed and how could that measurement become more accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Seebeck coefficient of the material is not already tabulated, then you'll indeed need to measure it yourself. This can be done in various ways.

- One of them is by measuring the Thomson coefficient of your material from nearly absolute zero degrees up to the temperature of interest, so you get $\mu(T)$. Then you can use Kelvin relation that links the Thomson coefficient to the Seebeck one: $\displaystyle S(T)=\int_0^T \frac{\mu(T')}{T'}dT'$
- By using a superconductor to complete a closed circuit. Since one measures $S_A-S_B$ where $A$ and $B$ stand for the two materials making up the electric circuit (it could involve more, or less, materials and then you'd need to adjust this.) and since a superconductor has a vanishing Seebeck coefficient, you would measure the absolute Seebeck coefficient of your material. The drawback is that this can be done up to about $80 K$ which is the critical temperature of common cheap HTS. Above that temperature you'd need to use a material with a tabulated Seebeck coefficient to complete the circuit.
- By doing a standard experiment where you complete the circuit with a well tabulated Seebeck coefficient material. Essentially you establish a temperature difference across your material, you attach/solder say chromel to its ends and connect those chromel wires to your voltmeter. You would measure a voltage that when divided by the temperature difference yields $S_\text{sample}-S_\text{chromel}$.